# Array declaration problems

Tags: java, arrays, declaration

```
private Location [] 4dir = 
   {Location.NORTH, Location.SOUTH, Location.EAST, Location.WEST};
```

What is wrong here?!? I really can`t see it.

I want to make an array (or array list?) to store these locations.

expected is the error.

Comment: Add the language tag.

Comment: There's a typo in Location.NORTH (but that's probably not it)

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: you need to initiate the collection with `new Location` before specifying the elements in-line.

Answer (score 3):

Variable names cannot start with a digit. The name `4dir` is not a valid name for a variable.

Reference: [Java Language Specification paragraph 3.8](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.8):

> An identifier is an unlimited-length sequence of Java letters and Java digits, the first of which must be a Java letter.

Answer (score 1):

Variable names cannot start with a number:

```
Location [] 4dir //<-- not allowed

Location [] _4dir //<-- try this
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.

```
private Location.CompassDirection [] dirs = new Location.CompassDirection []{Location.NORTH, Location.SOUTH, Location.EAST, Location.WEST};
```

1. expected 4dir must be without 4.
2. incompatible types - now they are ok
3. missing new Location.CompassDirection

Now it works. tnx for the suggestion davek